# Сравнение введенных значений

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Пишу на FASM, есть следующий отрывок кода:

```
use16
org 100h

jmp start

    isEnought db 'You are old enought!', 13, 10, '$'
    ask db 'Enter your age : $'
    age db ?

start:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, ask
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0ah
    mov dx, age
    int 21h

    cmp [age], 18
    jl exit

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, isEnought
    int 21h

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
```

Но при таком коде, просто выводит на экран надпись `Enter your age`, а ввести не дает, сразу завершается, в чем проблема, и еще, корректно ли так проверять:

```
cmp [age], 18
jl exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, age
```

Я не знаю как именно воспримет FASM последнюю строчку. Но предположим, что написано правильно и он загрузит в `dx` адрес переменной `age`, а не её значение (в этом случае, возможно, вылезло бы предупреждение или ошибка компиляции). Теперь внимательно читаем описание функции `0Ah`, и видим, что она вводит *строку* (не число!). Более того, буфер для этой функции должен содержать максимальную длину строки в первом байте. А во второй его байт будет помещена длина введённой строки. Таким образом, код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
; первый байт - максимальная длина,
; во второй будет записано сколько на самом деле ввели,
; ещё 2 байта для строки
age db 2, 0, 0, 0
;
; ...
;
mov dx, offset age ; или lea dx, age, или как правильней в FASM
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h
```

(можно увеличить максимальную длину и зарезервировать лишний байт чтобы пользователь всегда мог завершить ввод <kbd>Enter</kbd>, но это уже тонкости, подробности см. в документации по фукнции `0Ah`)

А теперь самое интересное. Нужно перевести введённую *строку символов* (она начинается по адресу `age+2`, а не по адресу `age`!) в число. И только после этого сравнивать результат с числом `18`. Но это уже совсем другая задача :)

Вывод: сначала читаем документацию, потом пишем код. И никогда - наоборот.

Comment: А если не секрет, как прикастовать строку к числу?)
Я раньше только на высокоуровнивых ЯП писал, и немного на C.

Comment: @Razor, алгоритм стандартный. Идём с конца строки, читаем по одному символу [проверяем цифра ли, нет - ошибка]. Позиция `pos` последнего символа равна `0` и по мере продвижения к началу увеличивается,  `number += (symbol - '0') + (pos*10)`.